# Aggregate functions like min and max in lookup relationship

Tags: apex, trigger, lookup

I had two custom objects Organization__c (parent) and Employee__c (child) which were related using lookup relation ship `[lookup:orgnitation__c]`.

`fields for Organization__c:
name, total_slary__c, min_salary__c,max_salary__c`

`fields for employee__c: Salary__c`

Now for example, if i have records like

EmployeeAutoNumber  ---------Organization Name------Salary__c

emp01-----------------------------------H.R---------------------100
emp02-----------------------------------H.R---------------------200
emp03-----------------------------------H.R----------------------50
emp04-----------------------------------H.R----------------------25
emp05-----------------------------------Labour------------------625
emp06-----------------------------------Labour------------------825
emp07-----------------------------------Electricity-------------925
emp08-----------------------------------Electricity-------------250

how can i write a trigger to update the min_salary__c or max_salary__c in organization__c based on the salaried of the respective organization? In the above example the min_salary__C for H.R organization is 25 and max_salary__c is 200.How can i update in the HR organization using triggers ?

Comment: Is this for DEV501 assessment?

Comment: No @user320 i dont believe 501 assesments will not be such simple as this :)

Answer (score 1):

I changed my trigger like this to make it work for both insert and delete.

```
trigger rollupTrigger on Employee__c (after insert, after update, after delete) 
{
    Set<Id> orgIds = new Set<Id>();
    List< Organization__c> updates = new List<Organization__c>();
    Employee__c[] emp = null;

    if(Trigger.isInsert||Trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        emp = Trigger.new;
    }
    else if(Trigger.isDelete)
    {
        emp = Trigger.old;
    }

    for (Employee__c e : emp) 
    {
        if(e.Organization__c != null)
            orgIds.add(e.Organization__c);
    }

    for (AggregateResult ar : [select Organization__c i, sum(Salary__c) su, 
        min(Salary__c) mi, max(Salary__c) ma,count(id) ids from employee__c 
        where Organization__c in :orgIds group by Organization__c])
    {
        updates.add(new Organization__c(Id = (Id)ar.get('i'),
            totalsalary__c = (Decimal)ar.get('su'),min_salary__c = (Decimal)ar.get('mi'),
            max_salary__c = (Decimal)ar.get('ma'),total_emp_in_org__c = (Decimal)ar.get('ids')));
    }

    update updates;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger EmployeeTrigger1 on Employee__c (after insert,after update,after delete,after undelete)
{
    list<Organization__c> Orgvalues = new list<Organization__c>();
    set<ID> ORGIds = new set<ID>();
    map<id,Decimal> Sumvalues= new map<id,Decimal>();
    map<id,Decimal> MinValues= new map<id,Decimal>();
    map<id,Decimal> Maxvalues= new map<id,Decimal>();

    if(trigger.isinsert || trigger.isupdate || trigger.isundelete)
    {
        for(Employee__c Emprecords:trigger.new)
        {
            ORGIds.add(Emprecords.Organization__c);
        }    
    }
    if(trigger.isdelete || trigger.isupdate)
    {
         for(Employee__c Emprecords1:trigger.new)
         {
             ORGIds.add(Emprecords1.Organization__c);
         }  
    }
    list<AggregateResult > Outputvalues = [select Organization__c Acc,sum(Salary__c) Sumdata,min(Salary__c) MIndata,Max(Salary__c) Maxdata from Employee__c where Organization__c IN:ORGIds group by Organization__c];
    for(AggregateResult Ar:Outputvalues)
    {
        Sumvalues.put((id)Ar.get('Acc'),(Decimal)Ar.get('Sumdata'));
        MinValues.put((id)Ar.get('Acc'),(Decimal)Ar.get('MIndata'));
        Maxvalues.put((id)Ar.get('Acc'),(Decimal)Ar.get('Maxdata'));

    }
    for(Organization__c acc1:[select id,Name,Max_Salary__c,Min_Value__c,Sum_Of_Salary__c from Organization__c where ID IN:ORGIds])
    {
       acc1.Sum_Of_Salary__c = Sumvalues.get(acc1.ID);
       acc1.Min_Value__c = MinValues.get(acc1.ID);
       acc1.Max_Salary__c = Maxvalues.get(acc1.ID);
       Orgvalues.add(acc1);

    }
    update Orgvalues;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Trigger Handler:**

```
public class EmployeeTriggerHandler {
    public static void handler(List<Employee__c> emp) {
        Set<Id> empIds = new Set<Id>();
        List< Account> lacc = new List<Account>(); 
        List<Account> alis=new List<Account>();
        for (Employee__c e : emp) {
            if(e.Account__c != null)
                empIds.add(e.Account__c);
        }
        for (AggregateResult ar : [select Account__c i, max(Salary__c) ma from Employee__c where Account__c in :empIds group by Account__c]) {
            lacc.add(new Account(Id = (Id)ar.get('i'), max_salary__c = (Decimal)ar.get('ma'))); 
        }
        update lacc;  
        for(Account a:[select id,max_salary__c,Costly_Employee_name__c,(select Name,Salary__c,Account__c from Employees__r) from Account where id in :empIds]) {                    
            for(Employee__c e:a.Employees__r) {   
                if(a.max_salary__c==e.Salary__c) {
                    a.Costly_Employee_name__c=e.Name;                   
                    alis.add(a);    
                }
            }
        }
        update alis;              
    }
}
```

Comment: Trigger handler for the trigger. Here the parent's field is updated by the child field's value based on the salary field of employee who has maximum salary in the child record.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take some time to read [answer]. We look for answers to provide _explanation_, not just code. The answers on this very old, and long-since solved, post are not great examples of our format.

Comment: I'm not sure where the `Costly_Employee_name__c` piece came from, since it's not in the question, but it is implemented in a rather inefficient way. The `for` loop can be replaced by a subquery filter or `ORDER BY`.